# Spring config file namespace resolve

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-bean

Problem in my Spring bean configuration file. I am using Spring Tool Suite 3.4 and Spring 3.1.1 jars (MVC, jdbc, security). This is just an warning in IDE but when the application is loading into APP Server it is showing the following error

```
Spring Configuration File - login-security.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<beans:import resource='login-service.xml'/> 
     <security:http> 
     <security:intercept-url pattern='/home*' access='ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN' /> 
     <security:intercept-url pattern='/admin*' access='ROLE_ADMIN' /> 
     <security:form-login login-page='/login.jsp' default-target-url='/home' authentication-failure-url='/login.jsp?error=true'/> 
     <security:logout logout-success-url='/login.jsp' /> 
     <security:anonymous username='guest' granted-authority='ROLE_GUEST'/> 
     <security:remember-me/> 
</security:http>

 <security:authentication-manager> 
     <security:authentication-provider> 

       <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref='myDataSource' 
           users-by-username-query="select username, password, 'true' as enabled from USER_DETAILS where username=?"
           authorities-by-username-query="select USER_DETAILS.username , USER_AUTH.AUTHORITY as authorities from USER_DETAILS,USER_AUTH 
           where USER_DETAILS.username = ? AND USER_DETAILS.username=USER_AUTH.USERNAME"></security:jdbc-user-service>

     </security:authentication-provider>
   </security:authentication-manager>
```

```
WARNING. ERROR IN CONSOLE - org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/login-security.xml]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are probably missing the spring security config dependency in your pom.

try adding this to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: After your suggestion -    The classes from the spring-security-web jar (or one of its dependencies) are not available

Comment: I have not seen that issue before. A quick google gave me this.. http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/102538-configuration-problem-spring-security-web-classes-are-not-available-you-need

Comment: I created a sample project here using the same security context you have pasted in above and it is working for me so it might be useful if you could provide me the contents of your pom.xml file